# Automatically update Kubernetes resource if another resource is created

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I currently have the following challenge: We are using two ingress controllers in our cloud Kubernetes cluster, a custom Nginx ingress controller, and a cloud ingress controller on the load balancer.

The challenge now is when creating an Nginx-ingress element, that an automatic update on the cloud ingress controller ingress element is triggered. The ingress controller of the cloud provider does not support host specifications like `*.example.com`, so we have to work around it.

**Cloud Provider Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cloudprovider-listener-https
  namespace: nginx-ingress-controller
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/elb.id: "<loadbalancerid>"
    kubernetes.io/elb.port: "<loadbalancerport>"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "<cloudprovider>"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "customer1.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ingress-nginx-controller
                port:
                  number: 80
            property:
              ingress.beta.kubernetes.io/url-match-mode: STARTS_WITH
    - host: "customer2.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ingress-nginx-controller
                port:
                  number: 80
            property:
              ingress.beta.kubernetes.io/url-match-mode: STARTS_WITH
    - host: "customer3.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ingress-nginx-controller
                port:
                  number: 80
            property:
              ingress.beta.kubernetes.io/url-match-mode: STARTS_WITH
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.example.com"
      secretName: wildcard-cert
```

**Nginx Ingress Config for each Customer**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: <namespace>
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # ... several nginx-ingress annotations
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "customer<x>.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: <port>
            property:
              ingress.beta.kubernetes.io/url-match-mode: STARTS_WITH
```

Currently, the cloud ingress resource is created dynamically by the helm, but triggered externally and the paths are queried by script "kubectl get ing -A" + magic.

Is there a way to monitor Nginx ingresses internally in the cluster and automatically trigger an update of the cloud ingress for new ingress elements?

Or am I going about this completely wrong?

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: You could write a program using a [Kubernetes SDK](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#officially-supported-client-libraries) that [watches](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) one object and updates another.  This is a pretty common extension pattern; if the thing you were watching were a custom resource this would be an _operator_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll describe a solution that requires running `kubectl` commands from within the Pod.
In short, you can use a script to continuously monitor the [.metadata.generation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#status-subresource) value of the ingress resource, and when this value is increased, you can run your "kubectl get ing -A + magic".

> The .metadata.generation value is incremented for all changes, except for changes to .metadata or .status.

Below, I will provide a detailed step-by-step explanation.

---

To check the generation of the `web` ingress resource, we can use:

```
### kubectl get ingress <INGRESS_RESOURCE_NAME> -n default --template '{{.metadata.generation}}'
$ kubectl get ingress web -n default --template '{{.metadata.generation}}'
1
```

To constantly monitor this value, we can create a Bash script:
**NOTE:** This script compares `generation` to `newGeneration` in a `while` loop to detect any `.metadata.generation` changes.

```
$ cat check-script.sh
#!/bin/bash
generation="$(kubectl get ingress web -n default --template '{{.metadata.generation}}')"

while true; do
    newGeneration="$(kubectl get ingress web -n default --template '{{.metadata.generation}}')"
    if [[ "${generation}" != "${newGeneration}" ]]; then
        echo "Modified !!!" # Here you can additionally add "magic"
        generation=${newGeneration}
    fi
```

We want to run this script from inside the Pod, so I converted it to `ConfigMap` which will allow us to mount this script in a volume (see: [Using ConfigMaps as files from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#using-configmaps-as-files-from-a-pod)):

```
$ cat check-script-configmap.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: check-script
data:
  checkScript.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    generation="$(kubectl get ingress web -n default --template '{{.metadata.generation}}')"

    while true; do
        newGeneration="$(kubectl get ingress web -n default --template '{{.metadata.generation}}')"
        if [[ "${generation}" != "${newGeneration}" ]]; then
            echo "Modified !!!"
            generation=${newGeneration}
        fi
    done

$ kubectl apply -f check-script-configmap.yml
configmap/check-script created
```

For security reasons, I've created a separate `ingress-checker` ServiceAccount with the `view` Role assigned and our Pod will run under this ServiceAccount:
**NOTE:** I've created a Deployment instead of a single Pod.

```
$ cat all-in-one.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress-checker
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-checker-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-checker
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-checker
  name: ingress-checker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-checker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-checker
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ingress-checker
      volumes:
        - name: check-script
          configMap:
            name: check-script
      containers:
      - image: bitnami/kubectl
        name: test
        command: ["bash", "/mnt/checkScript.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: check-script
          mountPath: /mnt
```

After applying the above manifest, the `ingress-checker` Deployment was created and started monitoring the `web` ingress resource:

```
$ kubectl apply -f all-in-one.yaml
serviceaccount/ingress-checker created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-checker-binding created
deployment.apps/ingress-checker created

$ kubectl get deploy,pod | grep ingress-checker
deployment.apps/ingress-checker            1/1     1            
pod/ingress-checker-6846474c9-rhszh            1/1     Running
```

Finally, we can check how it works.
From one terminal window I checked the `ingress-checker` logs with the `$ kubectl logs -f deploy/ingress-checker` command.
From another terminal window, I modified the `web` ingress resource.

**Second terminal window:**

```
$ kubectl edit ing web                                                                                                                                           
ingress.networking.k8s.io/web edited
```

**First terminal window:**

```
$ kubectl logs -f deploy/ingress-checker

Modified !!!
```

As you can see, it works as expected. We have the `ingress-checker` Deployment that monitors changes to the `web` ingress resource.

Comment: At least I was able to specifiy a wildcard host for the provider ingress but your answer helps me a lot for other challenges. Thanks :)